# Interactive markers: launch on robot, or on desktop?

Tags: ros, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at how other robots are set up, there doesn't seem to be a clear consensus on this.

For clarity, I'm specifically talking about the case where a robot has one (or more) headless PCs onboard, and rviz is being run off-board, probably from a launcher part of a `xxxx_viz` or `xxxx_desktop` package.

Should an interactive marker server be started by default with the base robot bringup, or should it be launched alongside rviz, in the `view_robot.launch` roslaunch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151961/interactive-markers:-launch-on-robot,-or-on-desktop?/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2014-04-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it´s pretty hard to give a general answer here, as it depends a lot on the given application if it´s better to start things onboard or offboard. For example, if you want the interactive marker to be available to any user connecting to the robot via rviz, it probably makes sense to run it onboard. If you want to save bandwidth/reduce issues due to potential wireless latency you might want to start it together with rviz on demand  on your offboard computer (perhaps both together in a launch file as you suggested). The good thing is that multiple options can be tested pretty easily using ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3